# How to select Date and Time from one field in a datetime picker

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to have a picker that allows you to select a date and time?  This is my model for OrderDueDate and it only allows me to select a date:

```
  [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Display(Name = "Order Due Date")]

    public DateTime OrderDueDate { get; set; }
```

Comment: DisplayFormat is only including date

Comment: Are you using a jquery plugin or do you want to do this using the browsers datetimepicker (which is only supported in Chrome)